# How do I catch mxmlc ant task failure

Tags: flash, ant, mxmlc

I've tried using the `haltonfailure="false"` and `failureproperty="compile.failed"` but ant just throws an error when I try to run it: `"The <mxmlc> type doesn't support the "haltonfailure" attribute."`

I need to do a little cleanup before the build script exits if the mxmlc task fails, how do I achieve this?

Comment: see this posting answering a similar question =<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387319/conditional-task-on-exec-failure-in-ant/6391165#6391165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [ant-contrib try-catch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) support.