# ant - Running a target at the end of every build

Tags: ant

Is there a way to always run a target at the *end* of every build?

I know I can do something like this...

```
<target name="runJob" depends="actuallyRunJob, teardown"/>
```

... but that's sloppy, since I'd need a wrapper for every target that needs a teardown.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a buildlistener, f.e. the exec-listener which provides a taskcontainer for each build result
 ( BUILD SUCCESSFUL | BUILD FAILED ) where you can put all your needed tasks in
see [Conditional Task on exec failure in Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387319/conditional-task-on-exec-failure-in-ant/6391165#6391165) for further details
or roll your own build listener, see =
http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html
and the api docs from your ant installation =
$ANT_HOME/docs/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/BuildListener.html

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as Rebse's answer, you can write a BuildListener in Javascript as follows (if you don't mind trading an Ant extension against some code in your makefile):

```
<project name="test-ant" default="build">                                                           

<target name="init">                                                                            
    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[                                                    
        function noop () {}                                                                     
        var listener = new org.apache.tools.ant.BuildListener() {                               
            buildFinished: function(e) {                                                        
                project.executeTarget("_finally");                                              
            },                                                                                  
            buildStarted: noop,                                                                 
            messageLogged: noop,                                                                
            targetStarted: noop,                                                                
            targetFinished: noop,                                                               
            taskStarted: noop,                                                                  
            taskFinished: noop                                                                  
        }                                                                                       
        project.addBuildListener(listener)                                                      
    ]]></script>                                                                                
</target>                                                                                       

<target name="build" depends="init"/>                                                           

<target name="fail" depends="init">                                                             
    <fail message="expected failure"/>                                                          
</target>                                                                                       

<target name="_finally">                                                                        
    <echo message="executing _finally target..."/>                                              
</target>                                                                                       

</project>
```

Intercepting other events should be quite easy as you can see.

Comment: If the `script` is inside a target, the `buildStarted` and `buildFinished` event cannot be triggered successfully. It can be solved by placing the `script` directly under `project`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and ended up writing a custom task, which looks like this:

```
<!-- a task that executes the embedded sequential element at the end of the build,
    but only if the nested condition is true; in this case, we're dumping out the
    properties to a file but only if the target directory exists (otherwise, the clean
    target would also generate the file and we'd never really be clean!) -->
<build:whendone>
    <condition>
        <available file="${project_target-dir}" />
    </condition>
    <sequential>
        <mkdir dir="${project_final-build-properties-file}/.." />
        <echoproperties destfile="${project_final-build-properties-file}" />
    </sequential>
</build:whendone>
```

In this case, I wanted a record of all of the Ant properties that contributed to a build, but doing that at the beginning of the build misses quite a few (if they're initialized as part of targets, after dumping them to the file).

Unfortunately, I can't share specific code, but this is nothing more than an Ant `Task` that implements `SubBuildListener`, specifically `buildFinished(BuildEvent)`.  The listener tests the embedded condition and then, if `true`, executes the embedded `sequential`.

I'd love to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an android project you can easily override the "**-post-build**" target in your local "build.xml" file. This target is just for this purpose.