# In Ant, how is exception/error handling used?

Tags: ant, try-catch

In Apache Ant, how can i handle a failure?

For example, if i perform a build and it fails, i want to invoke some process before it bails out.

Basically try/catch type functionality.

Comment: see =>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387319/conditional-task-on-exec-failure-in-ant/6391165#6391165
for a similar question

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using 3rd-party library, Ant-Contrib provides `<trycatch>` task -> http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation about listeners](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html), and then build your own listener which listens to the `buildFinished` event.